# How to restrict the extent of the View

Tags: openlayers

We are migrating OpenLayers 2.13 to 4.6 and we are missing the mapOption restrictedExtent.

We have set the projection and extent on the view:

```
// Add UTM 32N projection to openlayers.
   const projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
     code: 'EPSG:25832',
     extent: [399916.43156493746, 6029933.383271052, 735845.0210636959, 6415806.634077875],
     units: 'm'
   });
   ol.proj.addProjection(projection);

   // Setup view.
   this.view = new ol.View({
     projection: projection,
     center: [574912.88, 6225260.8],
     extent: projection.getExtent(),
     zoom: 6,
     minZoom: 1.8
   });

   // Setup map.
   this.map = new ol.Map({
     target: targetElementId,
     controls: [new ol.control.ScaleLine()],
     view: this.view
   });
```

The map showed are limited to our extent area BUT it is still posible to zoom further out and getting white area around the map. It's also posible to drag the map aorund in 'the white tiles ocean'. This behavior was avoid in OL 2.13.

Is there a work-around?

[Drag map in 'white tiles ocean'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yydT2.png)

Comment: They only support an option to restrict center point, but the boundary. You can restrict the extent by calculating the coordinates which will be edge from some point up to the window size, but it's so annoying and not clear way from resizing window.